# ServiceActivator 'randomly' unsubscribing from PublishSubscribeChannel

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a method annotated with @ServiceActivator("CH1"), where "CH1" definition is:

```
  @Bean(name = "CH1")
  MessageChannel ch1() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel
  }
```

and other PollableChannels publishing to this channel via

`@BidgeTo(value = "CH1", poller = @Poller("myPoller"))`

Things seem to work fine most of the time; however, seemingly randomly the message handler unsubscribes from "CH1" and I see in the logs:

```
[DEBUG] (pool-2-thread-1) org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher: No subscribers, default behavior is ignore
```

Now I know I can change the minSubscribers but I don't get why things seem to randomly unsubscribe? After this error it will go back to handling some messages fine. Does a message handler unsubscribe while handling messages or if the executor being used is full? I see no errors associated with this in the log nor and unsubscribe or update to subscriber counts to "CH1" in the logs.

Answer (score 2):

That does not make sense. Please, share some test-case to reproduce from the Framework perspective.

The source code on the matter looks like:

```
if (dispatched == 0 && this.minSubscribers == 0 && logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    if (sequenceSize > 0) {
        logger.debug("No subscribers received message, default behavior is ignore");
    }
    else {
        logger.debug("No subscribers, default behavior is ignore");
    }
}
```

where we can go to the `sequence == 0` only in case of:

```
Collection<MessageHandler> handlers = this.getHandlers();
if (this.requireSubscribers && handlers.size() == 0) {
    throw new MessageDispatchingException(message, "Dispatcher has no subscribers");
}
int sequenceSize = handlers.size();
```

Only the clue that your subscribers unsubscribes somehow...

I see that you have a DEBUG for your `CH1`, so would you mind to share DEBUG logs for entire `org.springframework.integration` when you see that error.

**EDIT**

Also note that whenever a subscriber is added/removed (e.g. when a consuming endpoint is started/stopped), you will see this log message...

```
if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
    logger.info("Channel '" + this.getFullChannelName() + "' has " + counter + " subscriber(s).");
}
```

(when logging with at least INFO logging).

Comment: It looks like I begin polling before the handler has a chance to subscribe to CH1. I'm not sure the best way to handle this, but if I set minSubscribers and ignoreFailures to 1 and false respectively it works fine.

Comment: Yes, that may be. But looks like we have fixed the `phase` issue for the Polling Consumer once: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3475